# Создание изображения платежного чека из таблицы JTable

Tags: java, sql, list, jtable

Имеется таблица с информацией (данные получаются из базы sql), имеется ли возможность создавать динамические чеки (в зависимости от выбранной строки в таблице) и выводить их в формате png / pdf? Чек вида:
[image: Пример чека]

Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IText - сила. Прекрасно все реализуется посредством подключения данного модуля [(ccылка)](http://itextpdf.com)

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развернутый ответ, что бы им могли воспользоваться и другие пользователи ресурса по желанию или необходимости.